Issue with my homepage after custom domain setup on GitHub pages
Recently, I purchased a custom domain from domain.com and updated the DNS settings to point it to my GitHub Pages. In the DNS settings, aside from the four A records, I added a CNAME record with the name www, pointing to my GitHub Pages URL (username.github.io).
Before the domain redirection, my GitHub Pages homepage loaded correctly, both locally and via the GitHub Pages URL (username.github.io/repository).
However, after setting up the custom domain, I encountered issues with the homepage's styling.
In my _config.yml file, I set baseurl: "" and the url to my custom domain. In the _build_config.yml file, I have the following configuration:
url: "https://username.github.io"
baseurl: "/repository_name"
destination: "docs" 

In the assets folder, inside main.scss, I have $baseurl: "{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}"; 
Additionally, in the CNAME file, I added my purchased domain from domain.com. I committed and pushed all the changes to GitHub. However, when I open my custom domain, the styles from main.scss are not applied.
Any suggestions would be helpful!

you probably don't want to redirect your custom domain to the github url, right? you want your website to load under the custom domain. if so, pretty sure you can just delete your _build_config.yml. What you have in your _config.yml sounds right
